# Bootstrap: do I need licence to distribute project of bootstrap responsive design?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, licensing

I am using Bootstrap CSS for responsive design in my project. Do I need licence to distribute my project of bootstrap responsive design ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap does have a license. It's MIT, and the high level details are near at the bottom of [this page](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/). Full license is available in their project repo [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE).

I'm no lawyer (so you should check this yourself, or get your lawyer to), but in short you can use it for free, at your own risk. And you don't need to open source your project, or give your changes back to bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

The Bootstrap MIT license permits you to "use Bootstrap in packages or distributions that you create," as long as you include the Bootstrap license and copyright notice with the project you're distributing.

[Here is the rest of the information](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#license-faqs) regarding the license and distribution.